# How to compare e.currentTarget and e.Target?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting events on button click and background click. In background click I am getting currentTarget and Target both same but in case of button, I am getting different. How can I compare if they are equal or not so that on equal I can perform some operation?

Comment: What is a _"background click"_? Also, do you mean `if (e.target === e.currentTarget)`?

Comment: @Phil "background" seems to refer to clicking the element, but not the button inside it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`event.currentTarget` refers to the `element` that the listener was bound to.

Here in the demo we can see if we do actually click the `div` (possible because of enormous padding) the the match evaluator `e.target === e.currentTarget` is in fact true.

```js
document.querySelector('#test').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if(e.target === e.currentTarget) console.log('yes');
});
```

```css
div#test {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}

div#test p {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  Try clicking here and then the P
  <p id="test2">Test</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The [Event Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) has some properties of which 3 are the most important:

[**Event.target**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) - Reference to the *"origin of event"*. In layman's terms: *clicked button*, *textbox the the user has inputted text into*, *radio button user has selected*, etc.

[**Event.currentTarget**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) - Reference to the registered event listener/handler. If the currentTarget happens to be an ancestor to other tags -- then that currentTarget can listen for events for all of them as well. This is possible because of Event Propagation/bubbling, refer to [Event Delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) for more details.

[**Event.type**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/type) - Basically a click, input, change, submit, reset, DOMContentLoaded, etc.

---

> The key to Event Delegation is to find out if `Event.target` (which changes) is  **not** `Event.currentTarget` (which doesn't change unless it's unregistered to event(s).).

**Details commented in demo**

```js
// Reference <form>
const current = document.forms[0];
// Register <form> to click, input, and change events
current.onclick = current.oninput = current.onchange = manageEvt;

// Callback function passes Event Object (e)
function manageEvt(e) {
  // This is <form> - tag registered to event(s)
  const cur = e.currentTarget;
  // This is the tag that is event origin (clicked, changed, etc.)
  const tgt = e.target;
  // This is the event type (click, input, and change)
  const evt = e.type;
  /*
  "this" is currentTarget (<form>) 
  .elements is all form controls of "this"
  .out is the <output> id
  */
  const out = this.elements.out;

  // Clear <output>
  out.value = '';
  /*
  if clicked, inputted, or changed tag is NOT <form>...
  ...display message...
  Otherwise if only the <form> is clicked display another message.
  */
  if (tgt !== cur) {
    out.value = '#' + tgt.id + ' is Event.target for ' + evt.toUpperCase() + ' EVENT ------------------value: ' + tgt.value;

  }
  if (tgt === cur) {
    out.value = '#' + tgt.id + ' is Event.target and Event.currentTarget for ' + evt.toUpperCase() + ' EVENT';

  } 
}
```

```css
form {
  border: 3px dashed red;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<form id='CURRENT'>
  <button id='BUTTON' name='tgt' type='button' value="button">CLICK EVENT</button><br>
  <input id='TEXT' name='tgt' type='text' placeholder='INPUT EVENT'><br>
  <input id='RADIOA' name='tgt' type='radio' value="A"> A
  <input id='RADIOB' name='tgt' type='radio' value="B"> B<br>

  <output id='out'></output>
</form>
```